# Should I encrypt the password immediately after I got it from the web form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption

I understand that when we use MVC, once we get the user password. It should go through some layers till it is ready to be introduced to the database. So, should we encrypt the password immediately after I got it from the web form? or I can wait to encrypt the password on the database?

I do apologize if this is an stupid question, but Im just starting on this.

Comment: You must **hash** passwords.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not re-invent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven authentication system.  (Microsoft has several)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good starting point for reading on the topic: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.  As others have mentioned, I highly recommend that you don't reinvent the wheel of security.  Use existing libraries, and try to understand the process before writing any code.

To answer your question directly: If the person is creating a new account/password, I would immediately hash the password upon receiving it and store it in the database.  There probably wouldn't be any 'in-between' steps.  No real reason for their password (hashed or otherwise) to float around the application.  Make sure to follow the principles outlined in the article that I provided, though.

Not covered in that topic: make sure to also implement SSL/TLS.  This is another topic that will require some reading.  I don't know where your server is located (internal to a company or publicly to the world), but people tend to use the same password for different services, and if you don't protect their passwords as it travels from the browser to the server, their password could be obtained and used with their other accounts.

In conclusion - this is a big topic that really warrants some reading before writing any code. Security is **hard**. Make sure to take some time to read up front and understand what needs to be done.